# mysql select from more than 3 tables where data not present in one of them

Tags: mysql

For mysql experts, any idea on how to simplify next query

```
select vid, rid 
from (select v2.id vid, r.id rid 
      from visita v2 
      left join reporteproducto r on r.visita_id=v2.id
      where v2.fecha<'2016/1/9' 
        and v2.cliente_id in 
            (select c.id 
             from (ruta r, rutacliente rc, cliente c) 
             left join (visita v) on (v.cliente_id=c.id and v.fecha=r.fecha) 
             left join (reporte rpt) on (rpt.visita_id=v.id) 
             where c.id=rc.cliente_id 
                and rc.ruta_id=4565 
                and r.id=rc.ruta_id) 
      group by v2.id) as t 
where t.rid is null
```

Comment: Do you mean this works but you want it to run faster or look better

Comment: I'd be less concerned with "simplifying" the query than I would be about getting better performance.

Comment: In general, changing `WHERE x IN (SELECT ...)` to a join improves performance.

Comment: I think this would be better placed in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually MySQL gets better performance if you change `WHERE x IN (SELECT ...)` to a join between the tables.

There doesn't seem to be any point to the `LEFT JOIN`s in the innermost subquery. You're not using anything from those tables, you're just using the list of `c.id` that are returned. `LEFT JOIN` doesn't change the set of rows returned from the left tables.

Finally, you can move the `LEFT JOIN` with `reporteproducto` to the end of all the other joins.

```
SELECT v2.id AS vid, r.rid AS rid
FROM visita AS v2
JOIN cliente AS c ON c.id = v2.cliente_id
JOIN rutacliente AS rc ON rc.client_id = c.client_id
JOIN ruta AS r ON r.id = rc.ruta_id
LEFT JOIN reporteproducto AS r ON r.visita_id=v2.id
WHERE rc.ruta_id = 4565 
AND v2.fecha < '2016/1/9' 
AND r2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY vid
```

Comment: Maybe I'm on the totally wrong track (that's happened before)... but isn't the `LEFT JOIN` and `id IS NULL` an anti-join pattern? (Assuming of course that `id` column is PRIMARY KEY of `reporteproducto`, or is at a minimum, is defined as NOT NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` column in `reporteproducto` table is the PRIMARY KEY, or at least defined as `NOT NULL`, the condition on the outermost query, i.e.

```
where t.rid is null
```

looks like a predicate intended for an anti-join operation. It seems as if you only want to return rows where `r.id` is null, which would be rows from `v2` which don't have a matching row from `reporteproducto`.

```
  WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

And that eliminates the need for the outer query entirely. (Again, assuming that `id` column in `reporteproducto` is NOT NULL...) This should return an equivalent result. (I'm questioning why need to return `r.id` in the `SELECT` list if we know it's going to be NULL.)

As a first cut at possible improvement, eliminating the inline view:

```
  SELECT v2.id  AS vid
       , r.id   AS rid
    FROM visita v2
    LEFT
    JOIN reporteproducto r
      ON r.visita_id = v2.id
   WHERE r.id IS NULL 
     AND v2.fecha < '2016/1/9'
     AND v2.cliente_id IN
         ( SELECT c.id
             FROM ruta r
             JOIN rutacliente rc
               ON rc.ruta_id = r.id
             JOIN cliente c
               ON c.id=rc.cliente_id 
             LEFT 
             JOIN visita v
               ON v.cliente_id = c.id
              AND v.fecha=r.fecha 
             LEFT
             JOIN reporte rpt 
               ON rpt.visita_id = v.id 
            WHERE rc.ruta_id = 4565
         )
   GROUP BY v2.id
```

Before I went further, I'd want to look at the EXPLAIN output, and the available indexes. Before I re-wrote an `IN (subquery)`, I'd want to verify (for sure) that this is returning what it should. Fortunately, in terms of performance, this doesn't appear to be a correlated subquery, which could really eat our lunch, and our lunch box too.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

I don't think the outer join operations in the subquery are necessary. Those references to the `visita` and `reporte` tables aren't going to affect which values of `id` from `cliente` are returned. So, I think those references add unnecessary complexity. If those are there because they are supposed to have an affect, then they shouldn't be outer joins.

I'd eliminate the second column from the SELECT list... we know that's going to be NULL. (If there's a requirement to return that, it can easily be added back in.)

And I'd include the equality predicate on the `ruta`.`id` column. That's equivalent to the equality predicate on `rutacliente.ruta_id`, given the equality predicate on the inner join between `ruta` and `rutacliente`.

The format of what appears to be a date seems odd. I'm guessing that `fecha` is a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.  The normative pattern for date literals would be `'2016-01-09'`. I'll leave that alone, since I don't know what datatype `fecha` is.

I also don't like re-using the same alias for a table within a query. The subquery and the outer query both use alias `r`. That's not invalid, but I think that adds unnecessary complexity, or at least, adds room for confusion. (For example, I was thinking that `r.id` referred to the `id` column from `ruta`. But obviously, it's a reference to the `id` column from `reporteproducto`. (I think I already edited the text above to fix that misunderstanding.)  I'd use a *different* alias for one of those two references. I chose to use `p` for the `reporteproducto` table in the outer query.

Here's a second cut:

```
  SELECT v.id  AS vid
    FROM visita v
    LEFT
    JOIN reporteproducto p
      ON p.visita_id = v.id
   WHERE p.id IS NULL 
     AND v.fecha < '2016/1/9'
     AND v.cliente_id IN
         ( SELECT c.id
             FROM cliente c
             JOIN rutacliente rc
               ON rc.cliente_id = c.id
             JOIN ruta r
               ON r.id = rc.ruta_id
            WHERE r.id = 4565
              AND rc.ruta_id = 4565
         )
   GROUP BY v.id
```

Given the `GROUP BY` clause on the query, I think we'd be relatively safe (in terms of performance) to replace the `IN (subquery)` with join operations. Any duplicates introduced would be eliminated by the `GROUP BY` operation. (Depending on the available indexes, the actual execution plan, data distribution/cardinality, the following change might make it faster, or might make it slower. We'd need to test:

```
  SELECT v.id  AS vid
    FROM visita v
    JOIN cliente c
      ON c.id = v.cliente_id
    JOIN rutacliente rc
      ON rc.cliente_id = c.id
    JOIN ruta r
      ON r.id = rc.ruta_id
    LEFT
    JOIN reporteproducto p
      ON p.visita_id = v.id
   WHERE p.id IS NULL
     AND v.fecha < '2016/1/9'
     AND r.id = 4565
     AND rc.ruta_id = 4565
   GROUP BY v.id
```